# Unable to set nuget package as @Prerelease VSTS

Tags: build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, nuget-package

I'am currently to try to create a nuget package in a personnal feed.
My build & integration works well, my package is push with a custom build number.

But I have a problem with prelease & release.
I have two branches ( **Dev** & **Master**) and I want to set my generated nuget package from dev branch as **@Prelease**

As official documentation mentionned, I have -beta to my custom version but seems to the package is not set to prerelease.

Any idea ?

My Custom version number:

> $(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(BuildID)-beta

**EDIT :**

I provide a one drive link with **Restore**, **Build**, **Test**, **Nuget Pack** & **Nuget Push** logs

**EDIT 2:**

Here my Nuget Pack configuration

[image: Nuget Pack configuration]

Here my Nuget Push configuration

[image: Nuget Pack configuration]

[Logs](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmR4iabK3vowwDdOiIkjFfj2U86M)

**EDIT 3 :**

I change my feed and still the issue.

Other strange thing. I'm not able with nuget CLI to add my package with this command after using `nuget add sources` command.

> nuget install Askmethat.Hobbidea.Commons

I have a 404 not found but if I use Visual Studio For Mac, It works...
This is giving me crazy because I need to add a nuget.config for each project or class library.

Comment: How do you check the package whether it is prerelease or not? You can check it in VS (Manage NuGet package=> Check Include prerelease option) or NuGet command: `nuget list [package name] -source [xxx] --PreRelease`. (Note, I check it on web, botth @prerelease and @release return 0 result)

Comment: @starain-MSFT I check on web ( with the tags ) or in Nuget Manager. If i use the nuget command it returns 404

Comment: Do you mean the package isn't existing in the feed? Can you share the detail build/release log on the OneDrive?

Comment: No the package is under the feed, with the correct number version. But not under prerelease channel. You want the log for nuget pack or push?

Comment: Do you use nuget list command? Yes, the log for nuget pack and push.

Comment: Yes but it fails. Currently i'm user donet core & `dotnet add package` command

Comment: Based on the log, it isn't a Prerelease package. How do you specify the source? (e.g. dotnet add package xxx -s xxx or nuget sources add xxx)

Comment: i use a nuget config file to specify the source. So it look like `nuget sources add` command. I will investigate more about prerelease package. For sure i missed something in my configuration

Comment: What's the endpoint address like? Is it a v3 endpoint?

Comment: yes it is : https://askmycar.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/askmethat-feed/nuget/v3/index.json

Comment: What's the result if you push the package to a new feed? What's the result if you push the package on local machine manually, then add it to project?

Comment: I did not test yet. I do not have access to the machine. When i can i will try your suggestion

Comment: Can you add the other packages through dotnet add package command?

Comment: yes all is working perfectly for nuget & my own packages

Comment: So, just the packages are pushed through build have the issue? Are they in the same feed?

Comment: yeap. I will try to find a good documentation for nuspec configuration files. The MS doc is quite confuse from my point of view. If I find a solution I will post it here.

Comment: You added nuget.config to your project? Is there the related source in that nuget.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @starain-MSFT, He oriented me to the right way.

I revolve one part of my problem yesterday to have a unique version in **Package manager**

I change a little bit the build number format in VSTS :

> $(Major).$(Minor).$(Patch)-ci-$(Rev:r)

**Major, Minor & Patch** are variables created in VSTS.

In my **Nuget Pack** configuration, I added an additionnal propertie :

[image: NUGET PACK CONF]

And in my `.csproj`, I changed the hardcoded version to :

```
<PackageVersion>$(Version)</PackageVersion>
```

The version is correct for my nuget package. This correct to keep version like 3.0.0 available for release but the package still not in prelease.

EDIT :

It's seems to work for prerelease after a quick check in Visual Studio.

So it's resolved

Comment: Thanks again for your help and your time.